# Store and Retrieve auto-fill text terms, iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, search

I have a list of about 10,000 phrases (1-5 words each). When the user starts to type in the searchbar, I want to display a tableview that filters through these phrases to find matches. ie: it will function like auto-fill in your browser.

My question is: What is the best way to store this data? Should I just put it in an array that gets initialized when the user searches? Or should it be stored in an external file?

(I am working with iOS).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily do it with an array, but the performance would be very poor.
It would be best to have it in a SQLite (or Core Data) database and search that. 
I think having it in a file could be even worse performance than the array.

Comment: would I then perform a search query on the core data database every time the search term changes, or would i move the database to an array and then search on that? Thanks

Comment: It would be best to search the database each time, purely for performance. These databases are supposed to be optimized for quick searching.

Answer (score 0):

**Save it in a SQLite or Core Data database.** You could also use a .plist file, although that might take longer to read through.